# PHP file upload isset

Tags: php, file, isset

I'm working on a form and want to add a file upload to the following script:

```
//form validation vars
$formok = true;
$errors = array();

//submission data
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');

//form data
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//validate form data

//validate name is not empty
if(empty($name)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
}

//validate email address is not empty
if(empty($email)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
//validate email address is valid
}elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
}

//validate message is not empty
if(empty($message)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a message";
}
//validate message is greater than 20 characters
elseif(strlen($message) < 20){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Your message must be greater than 20 characters";
}

//send email if all is ok
if($formok){
    $headers = "From: info@example.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $emailbody = "<p>You have received a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p>
                  <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                  <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
                  <p><strong>Telephone: </strong> {$telephone} </p>
                  <p><strong>Enquiry: </strong> {$enquiry} </p>
                  <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>
                  <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

    mail("enquiries@example.com","New Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers);

}

//what we need to return back to our form
$returndata = array(
    'posted_form_data' => array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'telephone' => $telephone,
        'enquiry' => $enquiry,
        'message' => $message
    ),
    'form_ok' => $formok,
    'errors' => $errors
);

//if this is not an ajax request
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
    //set session variables
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

    //redirect back to form
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

}

I also want to restrict the file type and size, email a copy of the file (an image) and upload it to /uploads.

I think I need to use `$_FILES` but don't know how with `isset` - I'd really appreciate some help. The HTML element's id is `uploaded_file`.

Thanks,

I've added this to above code but am still having problems;

```
    $message = $_POST['message'];
$photo = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];

//attach file
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not attached a photo";
}
```

Clearly this is a validation issue - but can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> * $_FILES["file"]["name"] - the name of the uploaded file
> * $_FILES["file"]["type"] - the type of the uploaded file
> * $_FILES["file"]["size"] - the size in bytes of the uploaded file
> * $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] - the name of the temporary copy of the file stored on the server
> * $_FILES["file"]["error"] - the error code resulting from the file upload
> ```

- [link removed, see link in comments]

I believe this will help you. Edit for clarity: `"file"` is the `name` attribute of the file field where you uploaded the file.

Once it's uploaded, check out the examples [here (PHP.net)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) for what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, add

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute to your `<form>` tag and
`<input type="File" name="uploaded_file />` to your form inputs list where you want the upload button to be.

Then in your PHP script above add:

```
if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']){
   $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']); 
}
```

Comment: This does not handle failure conditions. You have to check `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK` before you can proceed with the processing.